# Angular change css settings based on condition

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I have a mat icon below I wanna change the icon and the settings based on condition

If `item.status =='Accepted'` I want the icon to be `check_circle` with color `#00B0DB` else if

`item.status` is not equal to accepted then I want the icon to be `check_circle_outline` with color `#BDBDBD`

How do we dynamically do it in Angular without creating two Material icons?

#my current one

```
<mat-icon class="custom" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon"
  [style.color]="item.status =='Accepted' ? '#00B0DB' : '#707070'">check_circle</mat-icon>
```

Comment: What did you try? What is not working?

Comment: the code above is what I tried

Comment: It seems like the color is set correctly. For the icon, you should be able to use the same syntax within `{{ ... }}`

Comment: So `{{ item.status === 'Accepted' ? 'check_circle' : 'check_circle_outline' }}`

Comment: color attibute only accept "primary", "accent" , "warn" as values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `check_circle` in your code

[image]

replace

```
<mat-icon class="custom" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon"
          [style.color]="item.status =='Accepted' ? '#00B0DB' : '#707070'">
  {{ item.status === 'Accepted' ? 'check_circle' : 'check_circle_outline' }}
</mat-icon>
```

[image]